# How do you know what package version you need in angular?

Tags: angular, npm, angular11

I had an asp.net core app on Angular 10.2.4, decided to upgrade to 11.
Ran: `ng update @angular/core@11 @angular/cli@11` it failed complaining of devkit. Uninstalled devkit, upgraded angular to 11.2.14 OK.

Now am trying to install devkit back.

- `npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular --save-dev` - fail - seems try to install v12 and depends on cli 12 also.
- `npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular@11.2 --save-dev` or `npm install @angular-devkit/build-angular@11 --save-dev` - fail - No matching version found for @angular-devkit/build-angular@xx

What's the right version of devkit for Angular 11? What's the general idea on how to find/infer/guess correct version of a package for a certain Angular version?

Comment: Before 12 it was numbered quite differently: https://github.com/textbook/salary-stats/commit/957fb8df6b267565f54e48158491d63f1b87e35b#diff-7ae45ad102eab3b6d7e7896acd08c427a9b25b346470d7bc6507b6481575d519L62. In general you can `ng new` up an app with the relevant CLI version and just have a look. Note to help other people with similar problems find this it would be helpful to include the actual error messages in the question

Comment: I did. its - `No matching version found for @angular-devkit/build-angular@xx` where xx is whatever you try - eg 11 / 11.2 / 11.0 etc

Comment: For that one, yes, but there are two other "fail"s without.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I go here (https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-devkit/build-angular) and I click on the `versions` tab. It seems with version 12 they have become semantic (meaning 12.0.2 matches with Angular 12) but for you I think you need version 0.1102.13. You can check out all the versions on that site.

Comment: To add to this a little, in the Current Tags section, they have the appropriate version according to each version of Angular, e.g. 0.1102.15 -> v11-lts (for Angular 11)

Comment: [@daddywoodland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/153782/daddywoodland) THANK YOU! I wasted so much time looking for this exact page. [This is the exact link that takes you to the versions tab](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-devkit/build-angular?activeTab=versions)

Answer (score 5):

On the right side of the site

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular-devkit/build-angular

It has the TAG referring to the angular version

Example:

12.2.17--------81.826------v12-lts

0.1102.19------36.756------v11-lts